# I am trying to create JSON object from JAVA arraylist and store it in single JSON array but getting NullPointer exception . Adding info in body

Tags: java, json, arraylist

ArrayLists: for example

```
list1 [lst1, lst2, lst3..]
list2 [l1, l2, l3, ....]
```

Trying to achieve below result

```
[
{
"key1": lst1
"key2": l1
}
{
"key1": lst2
"key2": l2
}
]
```

I have tried below code but it is throwing nullPointerexception and coming out of the loop

```
JSONObject[] data= null;
for(int i=0; i<list1.size(); i++ ) {
data[i] = new JSONObject();
data[i].put("key1", list1.get(i));
data[i].put("key2", list2.get(i));
}
log.info(data);
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: How does the question relates to _selenium_ or _selenium-webdriver_?

Comment: you have initialized the data as null. Arrays are fixed sized collections

Comment: @DebanjanB Because I am using selenium-webdriver  where I need to fetch data from website and convert that to JSON. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is

```
List<JSONObject> data= new ArrayList<>();

for(int i=0; i<list1.size(); i++ ) {
     data.add(new JSONObject().put("key1",list1.get(i)).put("key2",list2.get(i)));
}
log.info(data);
```

or using stream

```
List<JSONObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
IntStream.range(0,10).forEach(i ->{
    list.add(new JSONObject().put("key1", "val1").put("key2", "val2"));
});
```